# echarts4r doesn't show anything

Tags: r, echarts4r

I'm trying to plot a 3D contour plot with `echarts4r` and it's doesn't show anything, even if it doesn't give any error. I've tried to use also `plot_ly` and I had the same result.

Here is the picture of the result with echarts.

[image]

And here is the code i used:

```
lower_df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  # e_scatter_3d(y, DKQ) %>%
  e_surface(y, DKQ, wireframe = list(show = FALSE)) %>%  
  e_visual_map(DKQ)
```

The only thing that seems weird is that x values are on the range (-45, -50) and DKQ values are in the range (0.8, 0.95), hence I would have expected the axes had a tighter range compared with what you see in the picture.

Any advice or solutions would be very helpful for me.
Thanks!

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This includes your data!  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Where do you specify your `z` values in your code?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't share data. Even if I use z = DKQ the code doesn't work properly, but if I run e_scatter_3d() instead of e_surface() the same data shows a proper graph

Comment: You're not the first person to say that.  Try to repeat the problem with a widely available dataset: `diamonds` or `mtcars` for example.

Comment: with mtcars and diamonds seems to work or at least something was show in the plot.

Comment: ...which suggests it's a feature of your data.  Which you can't share.  Which means it's going to be difficult to help you.  Best of luck...

Comment: I found that the problem was that there weren't enough rows in the dataset. Thanks for the help!